# Throw actual exception from completeablefuture

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, completable-future

I am making parallel call using completablefuture like below,

```
public Response getResponse() {
    Response resultClass = new Response();
   try {
    CompletableFuture<Optional<ClassA>> classAFuture
        = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service.getClassA() );
    CompletableFuture<ClassB> classBFuture
        = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
             try {
                   return service.getClassB(); 
              }
              catch (Exception e) {
                   throw new CompletionException(e);
              }
     });

   CompletableFuture<Response> responseFuture =
    CompletableFuture.allOf(classAFuture, classBFuture)
         .thenApplyAsync(dummy -> {
            if (classAFuture.join().isPresent() {
               ClassA classA = classAFuture.join();
               classA.setClassB(classBFuture.join());
               response.setClassA(classA)
             }
            return response;
         });
   responseFuture.join();
  } catch (CompletionExecution e) {
    throw e;
  }
  return response;
}
```

I need to add try catch for `return service.getClassB()` as it throwing an exception inside the method `getClassB`.

Now problem I am facing is if `service.getClassB()` throws error it always comes wrapped inside `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException`. There is a scenario where this method throws UserNameNotFoundException but this is wrapped inside `ExecutionException` and it is not getting caught in the right place `@ControllerAdvice` Exception handler class. I tried different option using throwable but it didn't help.

Is there a good way to handle the exception and unwrap and send it to `@ControllerAdvice` class?

Comment: can't you create a `@ControllerAdvice` for `ExecutionException` and inside it check what it the cause of it? via `Exception::getCause` and delegate both the usual `UserNameNotFoundException` and `ExecutionException` controller advices to the same common logic?

Comment: What’s the point of `catch (CompletionExecution e) { throw e; }`? The effect of catching and throwing again is like not catching it in the first place. So you end up with throwing a `CompletionExecution`, not an `ExecutionException`. And why is the result of the operation a variable (`response`) that is not in scope? Is it supposed to be `resultClass`, the variable you declare and initialize at the beginning of the method?

Comment: (Note: I have downvoted here, for the several spelling errors introduced into your code when writing it out here. Code should always be pasted in order to not make these avoidable mistakes. I go easy on beginners here, but not 28K users).

Answer (score 2):

Your code has several errors, like referring to a variable `response` that is not declared in this code and most probably supposed to be the `resultClass` declared at the beginning. The line
`ClassA classA = classAFuture.join();` suddenly ignores that this future encapsulates an `Optional` and there are missing `)` and `;` separators.

Further, you should avoid accessing variables from the surrounding code when there’s a clean alternative. Also, using `allOf` to combine two futures is an unnecessary complication.

If I understood your intention correctly, you want to do something like

```java
public Response getResponse() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> service.getClassA())
        .thenCombine(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            try {
                return service.getClassB();
            }
            catch(ExecutionException e) {
                throw new CompletionException(e.getCause());
            }
        }), (optA, b) -> {
            Response response = new Response();
            optA.ifPresent(a -> {
                a.setClassB(b);
                response.setClassA(a);
            });
            return response;
        })
        .join();
}
```

The key point to solve your described problem is to catch the most specific exception type. When you catch `ExecutionException`, you know that it will wrap the actual exception and can extract it unconditionally. When the `getClassB()` declares other checked exceptions which you have to catch, add another `catch` clause, but be specific instead of catching `Exception`, e.g.

```java
try {
    return service.getClassB();
}
catch(ExecutionException e) {
    throw new CompletionException(e.getCause());
}
catch(IOException | SQLException e) { // all of getClassB()’s declared exceptions
    throw new CompletionException(e); //     except ExecutionException, of course
}
```

Comment: But that would throw a `CompletionException`? The OP is looking to throw whatever is in `e.getCause` so that his/her `@ControllerAdvice` is triggered

Comment: @Eugene the OP only talked about an unintended `ExecutionException`. Besides that, the answer shows how to catch such an exception and extract the cause, so any adaptation to other wrapper exception type should be a no-brainer.

Comment: youre right, but the no brainer part was also to slightly refactor the initial advice in spring. I think a slight edit would be appropriate, imho. I perfectly get your point, though.